# Corrupt jpeg will not open

Tags: jpeg, data-corruption, file-recovery

I have a Maxtor external hard drive which I store many photos on in the camera's raw format and also the converted jpegs.  I have the photos broken down into several folders on the drive.  Recently, one of the folders seems to be corrupted and many gibberish folders are added to the drive.  I have run a data recovery software that seems to have found the files and I restored them to my C drive but when I try to open any of them in PS or any other browser I get the message unable to open invalid jpeg marker, or the file is truncated or incomplete,  or if it does open it is just a black and grey image.  Most of the other folders seem to be fine, but I can't understand what has happened to this one.

Comment: This whole post is a statement, not a question.

Comment: How big are these JPG files?  0 bytes, 1024 bytes, or some reasonably sized files (a couple hundred KB at least)?

Comment: Isn't this question off topic?

Answer (score 1):

The harddrive seems to have problem. And I will recomend you as fast as possible to copy your important files from this drive to other (drive, cloud,...)

About corrupted files. From your words seems like recovery software find the filename, find the allocated disk blocks for this file, but information in those blocks is corrupted/missing/unreadable. And you can do one thing: recover from backup (or forget about those files)